# Aphrodite CSS overwriting margin and padding

Tags: javascript, css, aphrodite

I'm having an issue with aphrodite, where if I have my base-component set to the global selector for example `margin: 0` or any of the sides `marginLeft`, `marginRight`, `marginTop`, `marginBottom` set. Then when I try to overwrite one or the other, it doesn't take.

For instance a `div`set with `margin: 0` then I add another style `marginBottom: 10` doesn't work. Same is true in reverse. If `marginBottom: 10` is set and I set `margin: 0` it doesn't work.

https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite

Comment: any code for us to easily watch without need to download that GitHub package?

Comment: Are you familiar with `!important` and the importance of your css order?

Comment: @Harry I am, still doesn't help out this issue.

Comment: Check if Aphrodite css is changing your class names and then define the class names again in your own css file with `!important`.

Comment: They totally are, I just don't know the best way of overwriting styles with Aphrodite.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: [Object Key Ordering](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite#object-key-ordering)

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
ordered: new Map([
    ["margin", 0],
    ["marginLeft", 15],
  ]),
});
```

Note that Maps are not fully supported in all browsers. It can be polyfilled by using a package like [es6-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-shim).